# Are objects and subclasses the same thing?

Tags: class, object

Someone may have answered this already but I am confused. If I were to create a class named Bug, there would be objects such as Firefly, Mosquito, etc. But I heard that those can be subclasses from the Bug class. Can those subclasses be objects as well? And are both terms (subclasses and objects) interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

Firefly, and Mosquito would be inherited classes, or (less likely) subclasses, of Bug. Objects are instances, not classes. Think of classes like stencils, and objects like cut-outs. Classes contain the information to make objects, like what type of objects they are, what they can do, what information they hold, etc. and the objects are instances of these classes that actually hold the data.

For example, you can have these:

```
public class Bug {
  ...
}

public class Mosquito extends Bug {
  ...
}

public class Firefly extends Bug {
  ...
}
```

And each of those are classes. `Mosquito` is an inherited class of `Bug`, and `Firefly` is an inherited class of `Bug` as well. Objects are these:

```
Bug my_first_bug = new Bug();
Mosquito my_first_mosquito = new Mosquito();
Firefly my_first_firefly = new Firefly();
```

`my_first_bug`, `my_first_mosquito`, and `my_first_firefly` are all objects.

Comment: And it would also be reasonable to simply represent a Mosquito as an object whose class is "Bug", without making a subclass.  It depends on what you are doing and how you want to organize your code.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Polymorphism would suggest you do something like ``Bug mosquito = new Mosquito();``

Comment: So if a class can be used to make different objects, then when would you see subclasses of a class?

Comment: If you need to extend what data an object holds, or the behavior of the object, while using all the base data and behavior of the base class, then you'd want a subclass, or more commonly, an inherited class.

Comment: @Roberts: Can you provide an example please.

Comment: If you want to write special code that only applies to Mosquitos (e.g. they have a sting() method and have a blood quantity) then you would probably need a subclass.  If it's just a Bug with a different name and doesn't have things like that, you wouldn't need a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

No,

Objects are the instances of classes. For example

```
Bug my_bug = new Bug()
```

"Bug" is the class and "my_bug" is the object. I could have many objects of the same class.

```
Bug my_bug = new Bug()
Bug my_bug2 = new Bug()
Bug my_bug3 = new Bug()
```

It is the same thing with subclass. For example (in java terms) If firefly extends Bug, I could have an object of this type.

```
Firefly my_bug4 = new Firefly()
```

Regards!